# List filtering of users, returns empty object

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two list-filtering `inputs`, if used individually they work perfectly but when used together it returns an empty object.

the filters contain one simple search `Input` field, and one `select`.

they trigger an API call to the server which when used both looks like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user?&search=jom&type=admin
```

the `method` which this call trigger looks like this

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $search = $request->input('search');
        $type = $request->input('type');

        $user = User::select('*');

        $this->checkSearch($user, $search); // check for search
        $this->filterUserType($user, $type); // filter user type
...
```

the `method` `checkSearch` looks like this

```
    private function checkSearch(&$query, $search) {

        if (!isset($query)) {
            return $query;
        }

        if (!is_null($search)) {
            $searchTerms = $this->stringToArray($search, ' ');

            $query = $query->where(function ($query) use ($searchTerms) {
                for ($i = 0, $max = count($searchTerms); $i < $max; $i++) {
                    $term = str_replace('_', '\_', mb_strtolower('%' . $searchTerms[$i] . '%'));
                    $query->whereRaw("(Lower(name) LIKE ?)", [$term, $term])
                        ->orWhereRaw("(Lower(bio) LIKE ?)", [$term, $term]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and the `filterUserType` like this

```
    private function filterUserType(&$query, $type) {
        if (!isset($query)) { return $query; }

        if (!is_null($type)) {
            $query = $query->where( 'type', $type);
        }
    }
```

I've tried to check the `where` on the `filterUserType` method, to `orWhere` but this just returns values of both not combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I triggered a break on the raw query and it appeared like this

```
select *  from `users` where ((Lower(name) LIKE %jom%) or (Lower(bio) LIKE %jom%)) and `type` = %jom%)
```

When I switched the methods I got the right results.
Switching from

```
 $this->checkSearch($user, $search); // check for search
 $this->filterUserType($user, $type); // filter user type
```

to

```
 $this->filterUserType($user, $type); // filter user type
 $this->checkSearch($user, $search); // check for search
```

Still don't know why but it worked